# suma final agrupando filas

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, tengo esta consulta que luego muestro en una tabla:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cart_product
         JOIN cart_product_to ON cart_product.cart_id 
         JOIN product ON cart_product.product_id = product.id 
         JOIN cart ON cart_product.cart_id = cart.id 
         WHERE cart_product_to.cart_idt = cart_product.cart_id 
               AND cart.delegado = '". $_POST["deleg"]."' 
               AND cart.created_at BETWEEN '".$newDatemin."' AND '".$newDatemax."' 
               AND cart.client_email LIKE '%". $_POST["cliente"]."%'";

$result2 = $con->query($sql2);
```

La tabla:

```
echo "<table class='datagrid' style='color:#000'>
          <tr>
              <th class='datagrid'>Numero de pedido</th>
              <th class='datagrid'>Fecha</th>
              <th class='datagrid'>Cliente</th>
              <th class='datagrid'>Productos</th>
              <th class='datagrid'>Cantidad</th>
              <th class='datagrid'>Precio</th>
              <th class='datagrid'>Delegado</th>
          </tr>";


    while(@$row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo  "<tr>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["id"]."</td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["created_at"]."</td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["client_email"]."</td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["name"]."</td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["q"]."</td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["q"]*$row["price"]."</td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>".$row["delegado"]."</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class='datagrid'>Total Pedido: ".$row["totalpedido"]."</td>
                    </tr>"; 
    }   

    echo "</table>";
}
```

La historia está en que me lo hace bien, pero lo que me muestra son los resultados del pedido y debajo de cada línea de pedido el total del pedido.

Ese total de pedido lo tengo almacenado en una tabla aparte: `$row["totalpedido"]`, que contiene el id del pedido y el total sólamente, la cosa es que quiero que ese total aparezca debajo de todas las lineas del pedido.

Por ejemplo, piden un articulo a con precio x, un articulo b con precio y, dos articulos c con precio z, estos tres articulos tienen el mismo id de carrito compra, y este id tiene asociado el precio del carro total almacenado en bbdd, pero claro necesito que ese total se muestre tras los tres artículos pedidos, no se si me he explicado bien, espero que sí.

Gracias.

Comment: Joaquín bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Primeramente, en cuanto a la redacción de la pregunta, los fragmentos de código son para introducir código que se pueda probar aquí, tu código no se puede probar porque los valores que usa no se están presentes aquí, por lo tanto el código no funcionará. En estos casos usar fragmentos de código en vez de ayudar lo que hace es entorpecer el análisis de la situación. Por eso me he permitido editar la pregunta, quitando los fragmentos de código y poniendo los datos de forma que se puedan ver sin tener que desplazarse hacia la derecha (líneas muy largas)...

Comment: ... de ese modo es más fácil analizar el código. En cuanto a la pregunta en sí no se entiende muy bien. Lo que sí creo es que tienes al menos un error de lógica en la forma en que estás concibiendo las cosas. No sé por qué usas una tabla para guardar datos calculados, cuando puedes obtener esos valores calculando los valores de los mismos datos. También, el uso de `@` en el código no es recomendable... hace la depuración prácticamente imposible.

Comment: Buenas A. Cedano, a ver, en primer lugar gracias por la corrección, lo del uso de @ es sólo en las pruebas para no estar constantemente depurando, jajajaja, y por otro lado no quiero guardar esos datos, sólo los muestro en pantalla, por eso uso las tablas, la cosa es que consigo sacar el listado de pedidos realizados con todas sus líneas de pedido pero debajo de cada línea me muestra el precio total y me gustaría que fuera al final del total de líneas por pedido, por ej. un pedido con tres líneas pues al final el total, otro de 20 líneas, pues al final el total.... no se si ahora...